Facing problems saving JSON data to postgres using Python FastAPI
I am using python and Fastapi to build a project. I am fairly new to both the technologies, and now getting stuck at a task of uploading a JSON file to an endpoint and then saving its contents to postgresSQL.
Here are some details:
vehicles.json: It can have list of 500-600 entries in the format shown below
{
  "vehicleList": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "coordinate": {
        "latitude": 54.5532316,
        "longitude": 67.0087783
      },
      "condition": "GOOD"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "coordinate": {
        "latitude": 37.442316,
        "longitude": 38.0087783
      },
      "condition": "BREAKDOWM"
    },
  ]
}

connect.py:
vehicle_data = Table(
    "vehicle_data",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("coordinates", ARRAY(Float), nullable=False),
    Column("condition", String(6), nullable=False),
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
)

router.py:
@router.post("/upload")
async def upload_json(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        # Read the uploaded file as bytes
        contents = await file.read()
        # Decode the bytes to string assuming it's JSON
        decoded_content = contents.decode("utf-8")
        # Parse the JSON content
        json_data = json.loads(decoded_content)
        fields = [
            'coordinates', #List of floats
            'condition', #str
            'id' #int
        ]
        for item in json_data:
            my_data = [tuple(item[field] for field in fields) for item in json_data]
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO vehicle_data (coordinates, condition, id) VALUES %s"
            execute_values(insert_query, tuple(my_data))
        return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "JSON file uploaded successfully", "data": json_data})
    
    except Exception as e:
        return JSONResponse(content={"error": str(e)}, status_code=500)

Expected output: I want to only store all the entries of JSON into postgress rows

What I tried:
I tried reading about file upload on fastapi as well as went through multiple stackoverflow questions, and even found a question that was close to the solution I am trying which is:
for item in json_data:
    my_data = [tuple(item[field] for field in fields) for item in json_data]
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO vehicle_data (coordinates, condition, id) VALUES %s"
    execute_values(insert_query, tuple(my_data))

But I suspect that the mistake is somewhere in the above code which I am not able to solve, I am able to correctly parse data in the form of python dict object till json_data = json.loads(decoded_content) line.
It'll be very helpful if you just help me to point in right direction or state what needs to be replaced instead of the lines written above.
Here is the error I am getting:

Have a great day!

@snakecharmerb - I have updated the question with an image from swagger response, I am not able to get past this, and in the command line it only throws 500 internal server error

The iteration over json_data is wrong. Try adding some print statements, or run it through a debugger.

Note that the outer loop over json_data seems to be redundant as you loop over it in the list comprehension, but it may be easier to debug a for loop that a list comp.

@snakecharmerb yes, when I tried to debug json.loads(contents) giving me <class 'dict'> and I am trying to convert this dictionary into a JSON payload by doing json.dumps(dict_data, indent = 4) however the output now is coming as <class 'str'>. I am trying to find some ways so that I can get a pure JSON value format out of this.

this probably means the data that I am expecting to get sent to the database is supposed to be JSON, but it is sending out an object converted into string.

There is NO pure JSON. JSON means string with data (which you can write in file, or send by network to other computer, or send to database). JSON only defines how to format to string to make it useful for other programs.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

execute_values runs INSERT for all items at once - so you don't need external for item in json_data

I'm not sure but I think you should work with json_data["vehicleList"] instead of json_data. Current json_data is a dictionary with field vehicleList (which keeps list of items) but you have to work directly with list of iltems. But only print() can confirm if you work with correct data.
